# different PYSTARTUP variables for different python installations

Tags: python, environment-variables

We have an in-house developed network-based application that is based on python, it provides a command-line environment in the same way like python does. I also have a local python installation on my machine. Sometimes for simple python tasks, i prefer using my local python install... Is possible to to have a different PYSTARTUP env variable for each of installation?

Answer (score 0):

You can always `export PYSTARTUP="whatever"` on the shell before starting your script.

You can also put `PYSTARTUP="whatever"` in front of the command you want to run, e.g. `PYSTARTUP="whatever" python something.py`